# GNU Radio passing strings from a bash command into a GR block label

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

So I am designing something with gnuradio, and the design uses PlutoSDR source and sink blocks. These blocks need to read the Pluto device's URI so that they communicate with the device.

However every time I disconnect and reconnect the device a new URI pops, and I need to change it manually in the block everytime before I run the design.

I trued using a python block in gnuradio to get the device's URI, but I am not able to pass the string that has the URI name as an output to a string variable in gnuradio, so that the name reading process is done automatically.

Is there a way to do this (i.e. output strings from python blocks) ?

This is the code of the block

```
def __init__(self, filename="/home/cheikh/Desktop/file.txt", time_period=0.08,):  # only default arguments here 
    """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
    gr.sync_block.__init__(
        self,
        name='Variable Read',   # will show up in GRC
        in_sig=[],
        out_sig=[np.float32, np.float32, np.float32, np.int32]
    )
    device_ul = os.system('iio_info -S usb | grep -o "\[.*\]" | sed  "s/\[//;s/\]//" | sed -n 1p')
    device_dl = os.system('iio_info -S usb | grep -o "\[.*\]" | sed  "s/\[//;s/\]//" | sed -n 2p')
    self.filename = filename
    self.time_period = time_period
```

How can I output the results in the variables "device_ul" and "device_dl", if the block outputs are "complex, float, int, short, byte".

The following is the output of the "iio_info -S", and I extract with the piped command the URI that is between the brackets (i.e. usb:3.16.5, and 3.17.5).

```
**my_user@my_host:~$** iio_info -S
Library version: 0.23 (git tag: v0.23)
Compiled with backends: local xml ip usb
Available contexts:
    0: 0456:b673 (Analog Devices Inc. PlutoSDR (ADALM-PLUTO)), serial=1044730a1997000308002600b6e27b7583 [usb:3.16.5]
    1: 0456:b673 (Analog Devices Inc. PlutoSDR (ADALM-PLUTO)), serial=1044739659930001200022003d35290588 [usb:3.17.5]
```

Reconnecting the PlutoSDR again changes this URI above, hence my need to automate this process.

Below You can see my gnuradio model (annotated)

[GNURADIO model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArAoN.png)

When I double click PlutoSDR source or sink, I insert the URI in the box where it says device URI as shown in the age below. Here I will put (if possible) my string variable that has the new URI.

[image: PlutoSDR Source]

An alternative solution, anyone knows how I can make the URI static if the above solution is not possible

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT:** I provided more info in my question as requested

Comment: OK, I've read the following [tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Creating_Your_First_Block) and your example makes a little more sense now. However, I think it would be good if you could show how you were doing this manually and then people could help you automate it.

Comment: @ukBaz I have added more info, in my question. Sorry if it seemed ambiguous previously

Comment: Thank you for the update. Very helpful. One more question... when you were modifying the code manually, where did you add the value of the URI's?

Comment: I updated my answer, baisically I just double click the source or the sink block and i insert the URI

Comment: Hmm? I'm probably not skilled enough in gnuradio at this point to be any help. It does seem that those two blocks are in different scopes so there doesn't seem to be a way to pass messages between them as I'm assuming you can't get access to the embedded python block `__init__` for the PlutoSDR source?  Looking at the following project https://github.com/oscimp/oscimpDigital/blob/master/doc/tutorials/plutosdr/99-gnuradio-audio/top_block.py they have a top block that creates an instance of `pluto_source_0`. It would seem like that is the right level to collect and set the device uri.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question where you were putting the device URI values when you were changing them manually.

Below is an example of how you could extract the values from the `iio_info` output.

```py
import re
import subprocess


def get_device_uri(serial_number):
    iio_info = subprocess.getoutput(["iio_info", "-S"])
    for line in iio_info.splitlines():
        if f"serial={serial_number}" in line:
            match = re.search(r"\[(usb:\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\]", line)
            if match:
                return match.group(1)
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    device_ul = get_device_uri('1044730a1997000308002600b6e27b7583')
    print(f"device_ul = {device_ul}")
    device_dl = get_device_uri('1044739659930001200022003d35290588')
    print(f"device_dl = {device_dl}")
```

This gave the output:

```
device_ul = usb:3.16.5
device_dl = usb:3.17.5
```